# Syntax highlighting in vi

Tags: linux, syntax-highlighting, vi

I use vi in Linux to edit e.g. JSP files.

The code is not syntax highlighted. I think this should be possible to enable, but I haven't found out how. Is this possible to do in vi?

update1:

```
# vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Jul 2 2009 17:46:42)
```

update2:

i tried to open files with nano through Putty ssh according [mnmnc](https://superuser.com/a/465222/107875) answer but unfortunately result is not change. I'm not change ***html.nanorc*** file
and it now have next text

```
syntax "html" "\.html$"
color blue start="<" end=">"
color red "&[^;[[:space:]]]*;"
```

Comment: lighted means you are telling about colour?

Comment: yep, syntax highlighter

Comment: for that use vim not vi

Comment: i have problem with installing vim to server because i didn't have enough permissions.

Comment: Which version of *vi* did you installed? ``vi --version`` might help.

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Jul  2 2009 17:46:42)

Comment: So you *do* have Vim. See my answer below

Comment: __Post the entire `vi --version` output in your question__. This will definitely conclude if your version is compiled with syntax highlighting support or not, and also make it very clear that it concerns Vim, not vi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/colorsyntax.png)?

[image]

If you actually got VI and not VIM, nano has pretty good syntax highlighting capabilities based on a simple regular expression. Configurable for multiple languages.

Look in the /bin/nano /usr/bin/nano if you have it installed. It should be in there. Almost every linux has it.

perform `cat /etc/nanorc` this is a configuration script for nano. You should have it. It contains lines similar to this one: `include "/usr/share/nano/html.nanorc"` and the file `/usr/share/nano/html.nanorc` contains specification syntax highlighting.

for example:

```
syntax "html" "\.html$"
color brightcyan start="<" end=">"
color brightred start="<script" end="</script>"
color red "&[^;[[:space:]]]*;"
```

also you can place .nanorc file in you profile directory to overwrite the global settings.

If it is still not working then I think the fault is on the XShell side. 
Switch to Putty and check again. In the Putty window you will have options on the left hand side. There will be Window->Colours option.
[image]

Make sure you have three first checkboxes ticked. It will work for sure. I think XShell made the output monochromatic for you.

Comment: so i've try it but it looks like that it's not work too or not enabled yet. One question. Can connection to server through ssh have any influence in this case?

Comment: nano should especially work via SSH connection. I'm using it myself this way. You should give us an idea what kind of Linux are you using. You can try to find nano by typing "locate nano" or "whereis nano" commands.

Comment: i have os Linux 2.6.18-194.el5 EDT 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux, i use XShell as ssh client

Comment: I do not think it matters what ssh client are you using. Once connected the environment on the other side is the same. Look in the /bin/nano /usr/bin/nano if you have it installed. It should be in there. Almost every linux has it.

Comment: yes, nano is installed, but i don't have any syntax highlight in nano, after open html file, i add pic to your post if you're not against

Comment: perform 'cat /etc/nanorc' this is a configuration script for nano. You should have it. It contains lines similar to this one: 'include "/usr/share/nano/html.nanorc"' and the file '/usr/share/nano/html.nanorc' contains specification syntax highlighting. for example: "syntax "html" "\.html$"
color brightcyan start="<" end=">"
color brightred start="<script" end="</script>"
color red "&[^;[[:space:]]]*;"" i will place this in my answer for the sake of clarity.

Comment: i have next lines:   syntax "html" "\.html$"
color blue start="<" end=">"
color red "&[^;[[:space:]]]*;" inside this file

Comment: I think the fault is on the XShell side. Switch to Putty and check again. In the putty window you will have options on the left hand side. There will be Window->Colours option. Make sure you have three first checkboxes ticked. It will work for sure. I think XShell made the output monochromatic for you.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that you were right, i connect through xsheel to another server and open jsp with vi and highligting is exist in this file, but when i opened the previous connection i see only green text, i try to create new connection with default parameters but textcolor not change instead of good highlighting on another server. Strange magic. Maybe anybody knows what properties i need to change?

Answer (score 2):

`vi` on Linux is almost certainly actually `vim`. You can check this as follows

```
# vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Mar  5 2011 21:36:07)
```

`vim` does support colour syntax highlighting. However it only does so on terminals that support ANSI colour not on monochrome terminals. Check the value of your TERM variable.

```
# echo $TERM
xterm
```

Then check if that terminal type supports colours

```
# infocmp xterm | grep color
        colors#8, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, pairs#64,
```

In a vim session you can also change this setting

```
:set term=color_xterm
:set term=ansi
```

etc

Syntax highlighting only works for files that vim recognises as being a file for which it has a set of highlighting rules. If you read vim's help, you can find out how to add your own highlighting rules files

Comment: thnx for information,i'll try

Answer (score 1):

This is vi

[image]

This is vim

vim means improved version of vi

[image]

Comment: ok, thats means that its impossible in vi, so sad

Comment: If I get any alternate method then I will inform you ok.

Comment: it'll be great, thnx raj

Comment: use emacs It will highlight the colour

Comment: thnx for advice

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explicitly turn highlighting on. Try

```
:syntax on
```

and

```
:help syntax
```

Comment: Thnx for answer. i try :syntax on no effect. :help syntax sais that E433: No tags file
E149: Sorry, no help for syntax. It looks like that this module is not installed

Comment: @BrianAgnew Yoshi got a monochromatic shell output (green on black) - probably because of XShell configuration. It's not the matter of VI/VIM config or lack of the editor itself.